# How is the constant "284" derived within the Solar Declination Angle equation?

Tags: earth, geometry, sun

How is the constant "284" derived within the Solar Declination Angle equation?

> The earth's axis results in a day-by-day variation of the angle
>   between the earth-sun line and the earth's equatorial plane
>   called the solar declination $\delta$. This angle may be estimated by
>   the following equation [6]:
>   $$ \delta = 23.45° \sin\left[\frac{360°}{365}(284+N)\right], \tag{2.1}$$
>   where $N =$ year day, with January 1 $+ 1$.

from [ScienceDirect Topics: Solar Declination](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/solar-declination)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to get the correct phase, so that for $N=81$ (which is March 21, the March equinox) the result will be $\delta=0$, as shown in the graph below.

[image]

<sub>Image from [REUK.co.uk: Solar declination](http://www.reuk.co.uk/wordpress/solar/solar-declination/)</sub>